# Generating transects perpendicular to track generated from a PPK GPX file

Tags: qgis-plugins, tracklog

I am new to QGIS and barely getting the hang of it so this question is quite simple. I have a route in a GPX file a generated from a PPK I took along the shore during a high tide. I would like to generate transects perpendicular to this track with a spacing of, lets say every 5 m and a length of 20 m each. Any suggestions as to what pluggin or tool I may use to delimit this area?

Answer (score 6):

**QGIS 3.0**

(1) Run `Densify by interval` and set interval to `5.0` meters.

[image]

---

*[EDIT]* following comment by @ndawson;

(2) There is a new geoalgorithm **Transect** (QGIS 3.0 `Vector geometry`).

Just activate this tool and set `length` to 20 and `Angle` to 90, then select `left`, `right`, or `both`.

[image]

---

**Below... useless part... please ignore...**

(2) Run `Extract vertices` on the *Densified* layer.

[image]

(3) Open the attribute table of *Vertices* layer to see if there is `angle` field. (You can skip this).

[image]

(4) Start `Geometry by expression` and (aa) Select `Vertices` as input layer, (bb) Select `Line` as output geometry and (cc) Click on large epsilon mark.

[image]

(5) Enter this expression:

```
make_line($geometry, translate(translate($geometry, 20, 20), 
                                         20*cos(radians("angle"+90)), 
                                         20*sin(radians("angle"+90))))
```

[image]

Final output is like the above... sorry, line length are not kept at 20m. Hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: In 3 there's actually a transect lines algorithm built in - this saves  all the manual expression based steps

Comment: Oops! I did it again... Thanks so much @ndawson Will update my post.

Comment: Wow, super useful! I will give it a try. Thanks for the step by step explanation!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the 'densify by interval' method does not set vertices at a precise distance, it only uses it as maximum value

please try the following instead:

1- use "Points along geometry" and set distance, this creates a layer with points and their angle

2- from Processing Toolbox open Geometry by expression and type (output geometry type set to line):

```
 make_line(
              project($geometry,10,radians("angle"-90)),
              project($geometry,10,radians("angle"+90))
              )
```

to create a new linestring layer with the required transects